# Map reduce in Hbase-1.1.x versions

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, mapreduce, hbase

As per the example in http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#mapreduce.example , I need to use `TableMapReduceUtil` for initiating map reduce over HBase and my Mapper will be extending `TableMapper`. But, I don't find those classes in Hbase 1.1.2 or 1.1.1.

In these versions, I need help on how to do a map reduce job over HBase.

I am downloading the HBase dependency as pom and not jar. Because, jar wasn't working and throwing error that maven could not find that repo.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

PS: When I tried to auto import in IntelliJ, it did work, but I had to import 0.94.x version which I do not want to use. Because, the hbase-client I am using is 1.1.2 and incompatible with 0.94.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need hbase-server dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```